# Android com.android.camera.action.CROP app closes automatically

Tags: android, image, crop, resolution

Trying to crop image in 896X504 resolution. image gets cropped but when cropping is done i see the cropped image in my gallery. My application does not receive any URI of the cropped image. What I want is a high resolution cropped image maintaining 16:9 aspect ratio. I also want to make that cropping rectangle or square to be fixed in 16:9.

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are [many image cropping libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) available. Please use one.

Comment: yes it does uses gallery's default crop functionality

Comment: you can also use third party library for this.

Comment: any suggestions? so that i can achieve what i have described.

Answer (score 0):

> My application does not receive any URI of the cropped image.

The particular activity that handled your request simply does not return a result, then. That's perfectly fine, considering that [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html).

> yes it does uses gallery's default crop functionality

There are ~1.5 billion Android devices, from thousands of device models. They have hundreds of default "gallery" implementations, in addition to third-party apps that the user might download. None have to have a `CROP` `Intent`, because that is not part of the Android SDK. Even if they have an `Intent` that responds to that action, there is no requirement for them to honor any particular extras, return any particular value, or have any particular functionality.

> What I want is a high resolution cropped image maintaining 16:9 aspect ratio. I also want to make that cropping rectangle or square to be fixed in 16:9.

See if [an existing library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) has that functionality. If not, try adding support for these features to the library. Otherwise, you will need to write your own image cropping code.

Comment: its returns cropped image URI for an smaller image output resolution like for 300X300

Comment: @PritamKadam: Again, the behavior of undocumented, unsupported actions like `CROP` will be unpredictable.